# Using connection service based by params

Tags: eclipse-scout

I have many services extending MsSQLAbstractService class, each for single database. For my application I need to connect to the proper database based on a parameter in the request.

How can I pass such a parameter and make the SQL class use the service I want?
I created my own SQL class, when passing the ID manually everything works, but I need to pass it from the request. How can I pass that param from request to SQL class?

Comment: Where do you get your parameter from? Is it passed with every request, or do you have to deduce it from the path of the request?

Comment: I would like to get it from URL. Like subdomain or URL parameter &id=5

Answer (score 0):

**Extracting the parameter**

Depends on your requirements:

- Service call from front end: Probably you could register a `@Replace`-Annotated `ServiceTunnelServlet`-subclass and extract it from the request there.
- Alternatively, there also is a thread-local that keeps the request for service tunnel calls: `IHttpServletRoundtrip.CURRENT_HTTP_SERVLET_REQUEST`. If you can easily extract it from the URL or header: great
- REST call to your backend: Extract it in the appropriate Servlet

**Storing the parameter**

You can wrap method calls in a ServerRunContext, and pass properties along that you can extract at other locations! See the `ServerRunContext#withProperty(String,String)` method.

You can create a new Context using the `ServerRunContexts` helper methods.

**Using it**

This part you already seem to have solved: You can use a single registered Service or appropriate `@Order` annotation to get the request and then dispatch them to the proper service based on the ID that you stored in the ServerRunContext.